# How to subset a pandas series based on value?

Tags: pandas, series

I have a pandas series object, and i want to subset it based on a value

for example:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

how can i subset it so i can get a series object containing only elements greater or under x value. ?

Comment: By "greater or under `x`" you mean "not equal to `x`"?

Comment: You now have the requisite rep to upvote the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you are referring to [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) on a series.

Greater than `x`:

```
x = 5
>>> s[s > x]  # Alternatively, s[s.gt(x)].
5     6
6     7
7     8
8     9
9    10
dtype: int64
```

Less than `x` (i.e. under x):

```
s[s < x]  # or s[s.lt(x)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "greater or under `x`" you mean "not equal to `x`", you can use boolean indexing:

```
s[s!=x]
```