# How to (efficiently, idiomatically) take elements from pandas series based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a `pandas` `Series` object, and I want to take all elements (meaning indices) whose corresponding values obey some condition.

There are many possible ways to do it, but I'd expect there to be a simple, efficient, idiomatic way - which I haven't found.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967848/how-to-subset-a-pandas-series-based-on-value) describes how to do it with boolean indexing, but this seems overly verbose for a simple command - for example:

```
import pandas as pd

age = pd.Series(index=['mom','dad','cat1','cat2','baby'],
                data=[30,30,3,3,1])

age[age>10].index.values
```

[EDITED: Do note that the variable name `age` appears twice in the previous row. of course `age[age>10]` is very short, but this is just because `age` is a short name - and if I'm encountering series with long names, like for example `age_of_family_members_after_filtering`, then `age_of_family_members_after_filtering[age_of_family_members_after_filtering>10]` wouldn't look so good.

The other solutions that I found are similarly verbose:

```
age.where(lambda x: x>10).dropna().index.values
```

or:

```
[name for name, _age in age.items() if _age>10]
```

(the last one returns a list while the previous ones return arrays, but both are okay with me)

Since it's a very common command, I'd expect something like `age.filter_where(lambda x: x>10)` or something like this, and I'm surprised not to find one.

What am I missing (if at all)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `age[age>10].index.values` sounds perfectly concise to me. Every part of that expression appears in the first sentence of your question.

Comment: Well, the word `values` technically appears, but it means the values of the `Series` in that sentence, and in the solution it means the values of the indices (i.e. to return an array and not an Index object)

Comment: and as for conciseness - the name of the series repeats twice, as opposed to `age.where(lambda x: x>10).dropna()`. I'd expect something like `age.filter_where(lambda x: x>10)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the row slicing in pandas accepts a callable. Therefore you can do

```
age.loc[lambda x: x > 10]
```

It looks a bit too much for this small example but:

- if the series name is not `age` but `series_long_after_operation` this become a lot clearer
- it supports method chaining like `age.loc[lambda x: x > 10].loc[lambda x: x%2==0]`

The second one is really the way to go for long piping operations where every method returns a different shape dataframe.

Comment: The chaining is a big plus where utilizing pandas capabilities... thanks!

Comment: If we mention chaining, we can also use `a.pipe(lambda s: s[s>10])`

Answer (score 2):

For the given solutions you can make some evaluation using the jupyter [timeit](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) magic command to simply test it:

```
# %%
%timeit age[age>10].index.values
--> 235 µs ± 8.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


# %%
%timeit age.where(lambda x: x>10).dropna().index.values
--> 510 µs ± 14.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# %%
%timeit [name for name, _age in age.items() if _age>10]
--> 12.5 µs ± 429 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Means for the given solutions the last one is the fastest, but the first one is the simplest and still perfectly valid one.

Another one, note the efficiency difference:

```
age.index[age.values > 10].tolist()
--> 16.5 µs ± 823 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

age.index[age > 10].tolist()
--> 157 µs ± 12.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

**UPDATE** with @Alexander's idea:

```
# %% 
from itertools import compress
%timeit list(compress(age.index, age > 10))
--> 119 µs ± 3.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: This question is not about timing efficiency, it is about idiomatic representation of boolean indexing.

Comment: But a non idiomatic representation in favor of efficiency is still worth consindering, in my opinion, therefore the timing comparison

Answer (score 2):

You could compress the index, but I don't believe it is any easier than simple boolean indexing which is quite concise IMO.

```
from itertools import compress

>> list(compress(age.index, age > 10))
['mom', 'data']
```

Comment: (I've edited my question to include that) I've though there'd be something like `age.filter_where(lambda x: x>10)`, but If there isn't, there isn't.

Comment: Note that `age[age > 10]` is more concise than what you propose.

Comment: It is, because `age` is a short variable name (which I wanted, for the example).  Maybe the example was misleading. If the name was `age_of_family_members_after_filtering` (which is similar to the use-case I've encountered in my work), it wouldn't look so concise.

Comment: Hence why one chooses short names to represent series and data frames, e.g. ‘s’ or ‘df’

Comment: ... isn't it conventional to use indicative variable names? Especially for series and dataframes, where you can often chain methods (e.g. `df.group(...).apply(...).dropna()`)

Comment: Personally, I use a comment to indicate a more descriptive name for a dataframe, or else reassign the longer name to a shorter one, e.g. `df = my_long_variable_name_for_a_dataframe`.  One does the same in SQL, where a long table name is simply aliased.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197240/discussion-between-itamar-mushkin-and-alexander).

Answer (score 1):

In my searches, I've found that for a dataframe (no equivalent for series yet) you can avoid the double call to a variable name and (which, again, might be a readability issue - depending on the coding conventions where you're at) by using `.query` (which is probably much worse than the accepted solution performance-wise, but still worth to note:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['mom','dad','cat1','cat2','baby'],
                data=[30,30,3,3,1],
               columns='age')

df.query('age>10')
```

results in

```
    age
mom 30
dad 30
```